# Polymorphic association - controller create error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I can't get it right - I have polymorphic assoiciation in my app and it works fine - I can add comments to movies or directors via rails console without problem. But using form I get error "uninitialized constant Comment::Commentable". Controller and Models:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_comment, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :logged_user

    def new
        if params[:movie_id]
            @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
        else
            @director = Director.find(params[:director_id])
        end
        @comment = Comment.new
    end

    def create
        if params[:movie_id]
            @commentable = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
        else
            @commentable = Director.find(params[:director_id])
        end
        @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
        @comment.user = current_user
        if @comment.save
            flash[:success] = 'Dodano komentarz.'
            redirect_to @commentable
        else
            flash[:danger] = 'Coś poszło nie tak, spróbuj ponownie.'
            render :new
        end
    end

    private
    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :grade)
    end

    def find_comment
        @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :director
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :comments, source: :commentable, source_type: "User"
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, :allow_destroy => true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :movies, through: :comments, source: :commentable, source_type: "Movie"
    has_many :directors, through: :comments, source: :commentable, source_type: "Director"
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :user

    validates_uniqueness_of :commentable, scope: :user
    validates :content, presence: true, length: { minimum: 40 }

end
```

I will clean up controller later, for now I just trying to make it works. Parameters passed in request:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"l+uouiN7H6hHArtiHGSw4MCsA8d37b60oDgNfskrTpwlDmJigLfBuMzYbA37mweInZEniVjzAzoPKB0dBRvJAA==",
 "comment"=>{"grade"=>"1",
 "content"=>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui,
 non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis,
 malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a,
 ultricies porta urna. Vestibulum commodo volutpat a,
 convallis ac,
 laoreet enim. Phasellus fermentum in,
 dolor. Pellentesque facilisis. Nulla imperdiet sit amet magna. Vestibulum dapibus,
 mauris nec malesuada fames ac turpis velit,
 rhoncus eu,
 luctus"},
 "commit"=>"Zapisz",
 "movie_id"=>"46"}
```

I don't know why, but user_id is not passed in request. Can you please help me? I Would appreciate any help!

Edit:
Form for comment:

```
<%= render 'shared/errors', obj: @comment %>    
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 well">
        <%= form_for @comment, url: new_or_edit do |f| %>

            <%= f.label 'Ocena' %>
            <%= f.select :grade, options_for_select(1..10) %>

            <%= f.label 'Komentarz' %>
            <%= f.text_area :content, rows: 5 %>

            <%= f.submit 'Zapisz', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
            <%= link_to 'Powrót', :back, class: 'btn btn-default uneditable-input' %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Schema:

```
  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.integer  "grade"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "commentable_id"
    t.string   "commentable_type"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end
```

Comment: can you post your form view?

Comment: Can you post your schema for comments as well as the entire stack trace please?

Comment: I'd recommend posting any migrations that create or affect Comment as well, just to ensure the `commentable_id` and `commentable_type` columns are there (or run and show us the output of `Comment` from `rails console`)

Comment: I have updated the post. Both commentable_id and commentable_type are present. Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't mention that error is raised by "if @comment.save".

Answer (score 0):

Ok it works. Problem was line

```
validates_uniqueness_of :commentable, scope: :user
```

It worked correctly after changing it to:

```
validates :user, uniqueness: { scope: [ :commentable_type, :commentable_id ] }
```